# Element not hiding using CSS

Tags: jquery, css, hide, display

This is a link called "Home" which I am trying to hide using CSS but it is not working.

```css
a.menu-item.shortpoint-nav-home-link {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode shortpoint-nav-home-link shortpoint-nav-a-selected" accesskey="1" href="/sites/somesite/en/Pages/default.aspx">
  <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
    <span class="menu-item-text" data-original-word="English">Home</span>
    <span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Any other way to hide it? Or may be using JS/Jquery?

Comment: Your CSS alone works fine, as you can see in the snippet I edited in to your question. If it's not working in your test environment then there must be another underlying issue - for example, the CSS selector not being specific enough to override another style rule. Check the element in devtools to determine the class which is displaying the element. Unfortunately without seeing more of the relevant code, we can't really help any more than that.

Comment: By way of troubleshooting, in Chrome dev tools: Inspect the element and right click -> Copy selector. Then use that selector in your css if it differs from a.menu-item.shortpoint-nav-home-link

Comment: Problem is this is SharePoint which adds hundreds if not thousands of extra CSS/JS code which may be causing the problem.

Comment: Right, but if you use devtools you can see the specific one which is causing the issue. Then you know what to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to hide just "HOME", change your CSS selector to the one in the below snippet :

```css
a.menu-item .menu-item-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode shortpoint-nav-home-link shortpoint-nav-a-selected" accesskey="1" href="/sites/somesite/en/Pages/default.aspx">
  <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
    <span class="menu-item-text" data-original-word="English">Home</span>
  <span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span>
  </span>
</a>
```